# How to set visible value inside TikZ based on calculation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I have the following beamer frame, which has two matrices, one with 4 columns, and another with 3 columns. The first one is displayed column by column as expected, but the second one is not. Specifically for the second one I have something like `visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+4->` and down for path I have `node[visible on=<\col+4->]`, but these does not seem to work. How can I make sure that the second matrix is displayed also column by column after the first one?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    automata,
    backgrounds,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    external,
    matrix,
    overlay-beamer-styles,
    patterns,
    positioning,
    ext.node-families,
    shapes,
    tikzmark,shadows.blur,fit
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Enc}   {Enc} % instead of \mathsf{Enc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PKey}  {PKey}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sim}   {Sim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prover}{Prover}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intuition}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\only<1-4>{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
  nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners,
  node family/width=samewidth,
  visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-4>},
  matrix of math nodes,
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm,
  column sep=.2cm] {
\begin{alignedat}{3} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \textcolor{blue}{\Sim(t^*, x)} \end{alignedat}
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, \textcolor{blue}{m_1}) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\& \& \&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\textcolor{blue}{\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}}, t])
\\
};
\path[nodes={align=center, above}] 
  foreach \Text[count=\col from 2] in {
    SSS-NIZK\\$\approx_c$, IND-CPA-PKE\\$\approx_c$, iO\\$\approx_c$} {
    (m-1-\pgfinteval{\col-1}.north east)
     -- node[visible on=<\col->] {\Text} (m-1-\col.north west)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\only<5-7>{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
  nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners,
  node family/width=samewidth,
  visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+4->},
  matrix of math nodes,
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm,
  column sep=.2cm] {
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, \textcolor{blue}{m_1}) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\\
\Delta_{t \to t'} = piO(\text{PUpdate}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t, t'])
\&
\Delta_{t \to t'} = piO(\text{PUpdate}[\textcolor{blue}{\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}}, t, t'])
\&
\Delta_{t \to t'} = piO(\text{PUpdate}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t, t'])
\\
};
\path[nodes={align=center, above}] 
  foreach \Text[count=\col from 2] in {
     piO\\$\approx_c$, IND-CPA-PKE\\$\approx_c$} {
    (m-1-\pgfinteval{\col-1}.north east)
     -- node[visible on=<\col+4->] {\Text} (m-1-\col.north west)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could make a minimal working example which does have all the libraries necessary to compile your code.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry, I put all the libraries that I use (and more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the result of this addition available for `beamer` so that it directly has an integer number on its hands.

We could mess around `\pgfmathparse{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+4)}` and use `\pgfmathresult` but that's not necessary.

For integer arithmetics, you can use

- plain eTeX's `\numexpr`

  ```
   visible on=<\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+4\relax->
  ```
- an uptodate LaTeX's `\inteval`

  ```
   visible on=<\inteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+4}->
  ```
- PGF's own inteval (undocumented)

  ```
   visible on=<\pgfinteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+4}->
  ```

Of course, I'll suggest an extra style to make it easier to specify:

```
\tikzset{
  column visible from/.style={
    visible on=<\pgfinteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+#1}->},
  column visible from/.default=0
}
```

This allows you to specify `column visible from = 4` in your second picture (for 5, 6, …). Without a value, the value `0` will be used and the behaviour of the first picture will be experienced.

I don't have a nice solution for the nodes between the nodes, here I'm using

```
visible on=<\pgfinteval{\col+4}->
```

again.

### Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  matrix,
  overlay-beamer-styles,
  ext.node-families,
  shapes,
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Enc}   {Enc} % instead of \mathsf{Enc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PKey}  {PKey}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sim}   {Sim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prover}{Prover}

\tikzset{
  column visible from/.style={
    visible on=<\pgfinteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+#1}->},
  column visible from/.default=0
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intuition}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\only<1-4>{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
  nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners,
    node family/width=samewidth,
    column visible from},
  matrix of math nodes,
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm,
  column sep=.2cm] {
\begin{alignedat}{3} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \textcolor{blue}{\Sim(t^*, x)} \end{alignedat}
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, \textcolor{blue}{m_1}) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\& \& \&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\textcolor{blue}{\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}}, t])
\\
};
\path[nodes={align=center, above}] 
  foreach \Text[count=\col from 2] in {
    SSS-NIZK\\$\approx_c$, IND-CPA-PKE\\$\approx_c$, iO\\$\approx_c$} {
    (m-1-\pgfinteval{\col-1}.north east)
     -- node[visible on=<\col->] {\Text} (m-1-\col.north west)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\only<5-7>{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
  nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners,
    node family/width=samewidth,
    column visible from=4},
  matrix of math nodes,
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm,
  column sep=.2cm] {
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, \textcolor{blue}{m_1}) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_1) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\\
\Delta_{t \to t'} = piO(\text{PUpdate}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t, t'])
\&
\Delta_{t \to t'} = piO(\text{PUpdate}[\textcolor{blue}{\mathsf{sk}_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}}, t, t'])
\&
\Delta_{t \to t'} = piO(\text{PUpdate}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t, t'])
\\
};
\path[nodes={align=center, above}] 
  foreach \Text[count=\col from 2] in {
     piO\\$\approx_c$, IND-CPA-PKE\\$\approx_c$} {
    (m-1-\pgfinteval{\col-1}.north east)
     -- node[visible on=<\pgfinteval{\col+4}->] {\Text} (m-1-\col.north west)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzvGs.gif)